# Code::Blocks duvidas

Tags: c, c++, codeblocks

1-como faz para colocar ele como padrão?sem querer no inicio quando ele faz a pergunta eu coloquei para não pergunta mais sem querer e agora mesmo reinstalando não aparecer mais.

2-tem como deixar ele em português igual ao Dev-C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1-como faz para colocar ele como padrão?sem querer no inicio quando ele faz a pergunta eu coloquei para não pergunta mais sem querer e agora mesmo reinstalando não aparecer mais.**

> Não entendi muito bem essa sua pergunta, acho que você gostaria que os arquivos ".c" e ".cp" abrissem automaticamente com o codeblocks correto?
>
> Então vamos lá:
>
> - 1) Clique com o Botão Direito no seu arquivo ".c" ou ".cp"
> - 2) Clique em Abrir Com
> - 3) Escolha o Codeblocks como programa para este tipo de arquivo
>
> **Ou da maneira mais correta:**
>
> - Selecionar o "Yes, associate Code.... C/C++ files..."
>
> [image: Codeblocks]
>
> **OBS**: Isto no Windows 10, como você não informou o Sistema Operacional que usava, eu escolhi o mais usado.

**2-tem como deixar ele em português igual ao Dev-C++.**

Eu faço a sugestão de você utilizar em inglês, o porque disto?

> - 1) Para melhorar seu inglês e Raciocínio na língua.
> - 2) Existe codeblocks em PT_BR porém foi desenvolvidos por terceiros, então poderá estar com vírus.
> - 3) O Codeblocks Oficial somente em Inglês.

Comment: Obrigado, demoro mais alguém respondeu!